# openam jar file for custom module development

Tags: openam

Where will I get the `opensso.jar` within the `openAM-12` folder?

This `jar` file essential for developing the custom module. The `amserver.jar` is named as `openam-core-12.0.0` and `opensso-sharedlib.jar` is named as `openam-shared-12.0.0`.

But `opensso.jar` cannot be found within the folder `openAM-12`. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a clear replacement for opensso.jar, from what I can see it looks like that it has been mainly separated into `OpenFM` and `openam-cli-impl`.